# LinkedList reverse addition

Tags: c

I am currently working on a leetcode problem with linked list that has me stumped. 
Problem statement:

> You are given two non-empty linked lists representing two non-negative integers. The digits are stored in reverse order and each of their nodes contain a single digit. Add the two numbers and return it as a linked list.
>   You may assume the two numbers do not contain any leading zero, except the number 0 itself.

Example:

**Input:**

```
  [2,4,3]
  [5,6,4]
```

**Expected Output:**

```
[7,0,8]
```

**My Output:**

```
[7]
```

my return list only prints the last value [7].

```
 struct ListNode {
      int val;
      ListNode *next;
      ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(NULL) {}
 };

/*Used to free a linked list in C*/

   void freeLinkedList(struct ListNode * aptr)
        {
            while( aptr != 0)
            {
                struct ListNode * temp = aptr;
                aptr = aptr->next;
                free(temp);
            }
        }
```

**My function:**

```
struct ListNode* addTwoNumbers(struct ListNode* l1, struct ListNode* l2) 
{
    struct ListNode * NewNode = 0;
    struct ListNode * curr;
    struct ListNode * L1, *L2;
    L1 = l1;
    L2 = l2;
    int carry = 0;
    while (L1 != 0 | L2 != 0)
    {
        int x = (L1 != 0) ? L1->val: 0;
        int y = (L2 != 0) ? L2->val : 0;
        int sum = x + y + carry;
        carry = sum / 10;
        struct ListNode * tempnode = (struct ListNode *)malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));
        tempnode->val = (sum % 10);
        tempnode->next = 0;


        if(NewNode == 0)
        {
            NewNode = tempnode;
            curr = NewNode->next;
        }else{

            curr = tempnode;
            curr = curr->next;
        }

        if(L1)
        L1 = L1->next;

        if(L2)
        L2 = L2->next;
    }

    if(carry > 0)
    {
        struct ListNode * tempnode2 = (struct ListNode *)malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));
        tempnode2->val = carry;
        tempnode2->next = 0;
        NewNode->next = tempnode2;
    }

    struct ListNode * aptr = NewNode;


    return aptr;
}
```

Been working on this for a few hrs and stump still somehow. Could someone point me in the right direction?  No direct answers please.

Update: After Tudatn suggestion I was able to get to work properly:

**Updated code:**

```
struct ListNode* addTwoNumbers(struct ListNode* l1, struct ListNode* l2)
{
    struct ListNode * NewNode = 0;
    struct ListNode * curr = 0;
    struct ListNode * L1, *L2;
    L1 = l1;
    L2 = l2;
    int carry = 0;
    while (L1 != 0 | L2 != 0)
    {
        int x = (L1 != 0) ? L1->val : 0;
        int y = (L2 != 0) ? L2->val : 0;
        int sum = x + y + carry;
        carry = sum / 10;

        struct ListNode * tempnode = (struct ListNode *)malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));
        tempnode->val = (sum % 10);
        tempnode->next = 0;


        if (NewNode == 0)
        {
            NewNode = tempnode;
            curr = NewNode;
        }
        else 
        {
            curr->next = tempnode;
            curr = curr->next;
        }

        if (L1)
            L1 = L1->next;

        if (L2)
            L2 = L2->next;
    }

    if (carry > 0)
    {
        struct ListNode * tempnode2 = (struct ListNode *)malloc(sizeof(struct ListNode));
        tempnode2->val = carry;
        tempnode2->next = 0;
        curr->next = tempnode2;
        curr = curr->next;
    }

    return NewNode;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Pay attention to how you (fail to) update `NewNode->next`.

Comment: Whjat is ListNode?

Comment: @MartinJames added the struct for the link list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the challenge of the problem is how to maintain the return list head pointer while still adding a new node to the list. One trick is to initially set the return list to NULL and check before adding a new node, something like:

```
if (result == NULL) {
    result = newNode;
    temp   = result;
} else {
      temp->next = newNode;
      temp = temp->next;
}
```

If you want to play more with this type of problem (i.e., linked list), more difficult challenge can be using recursion (either with support function). Have fun.

Comment: that was definitely helpful.